# How do you get a sqlite table schema using a query in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have been searching high and low, using many methods to get a table schema from a table in sqlite. Please forgive me if this has been posted somewhere else.

Current query is

```
SELECT TOP (0) * FROM 'TableName'
```

but this returns nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM 'TableName'
```

also returns nothing if the table is empty.

I also used `SQLiteConnection.GetSchema()` but it doesn't return the table in question; it returns a table with other columns.

```
DataTable dtReturnTable = new DataTable();
sqlitecon.Open();
string[] sParameters = new string[4];
sParameters[2] = sTableName;
dtReturnTable = sqlitecon.GetSchema("Columns", sParameters);
sqlitecon.Close();
```

Comment: the schema can be derived by the information in the "other columns" when using GetSchema().

Comment: I'm not a sqlite expert, but this worked for me to get the columns and dataypes: `new SQLiteCommand($"PRAGMA table_info('{tableName}')", connection)`

Comment: It's better to use single quotes rather than square braces as it's [non-standard sql syntax only included to support SQL Server's SQL flavor](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so that gives me a table with the tables schema and then I have to build the table based on the information in that table?
Is there no simpler way like (select top (0) * from TableName) < this returns a empty table when using normal SQL but it returns nothing in SQLite.

Comment: There's probably a better way. That method worked for my needs.

Comment: @Crowcoder do you have a example of the code?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have found some sort of solution, it isnt pretty but it works for my tables, luckily I dont have too many datatypes to work with, the biggest issue is I have multiple nvarchar types and multiple decimal types so I have to use else if to use contains. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was this

```
private DataTable GetSQLiteTableWithQuery(string sQuery)
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqlconlocal = new SQLiteConnection(sSQLITEconnstring);
            DataTable dtReturnTable = new DataTable();
            SQLiteCommand sqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sQuery, sqlconlocal);
            using (sqlconlocal)
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlconlocal.Open();
                    SQLiteDataReader sqliteReader = sqliteCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    if (sqliteReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < sqliteReader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            dtReturnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(sqliteReader.GetName(i)));
                        }
                    }
                    int j = 0;
                    while (sqliteReader.Read())
                    {
                        DataRow dtRow = dtReturnTable.NewRow();
                        dtReturnTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);
                        for (int i = 0; i < sqliteReader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            dtReturnTable.Rows[j][i] = (sqliteReader.GetValue(i));
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    sqlconlocal.Close();
                }
                catch (SQLiteException e)
                {
                    sqlconlocal.Close();
                }
            }
            return dtReturnTable;
        }

public DataTable GetSQLiteSchema(string sTableName)
        {
            string sQuery = "PRAGMA table_info('" + sTableName + "')";
            DataTable dtWorking = GetSqLiteTableBasedOnQuery(sQuery);
            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataRow dr1 in dtWorking.Rows)
            {
                string sColName = dr1[1].ToString();
                string sColtype = dr1[2].ToString();
                if (sColtype.ToLower().Contains("nvarchar"))
                {
                    dtReturn.Columns.Add(sColName, typeof(string));
                }
                else if (sColtype.ToLower().Contains("decimal"))
                {
                    dtReturn.Columns.Add(sColName, typeof(decimal));
                }
                else if (sColtype.ToLower().Contains("int"))
                {
                    dtReturn.Columns.Add(sColName, typeof(int));
                }
                else if (sColtype.ToLower().Contains("date"))
                {
                    dtReturn.Columns.Add(sColName, typeof(DateTime));
                }
                else if (sColtype.ToLower().Contains("bit"))
                {
                    dtReturn.Columns.Add(sColName, typeof(bool));
                }
            }
            return dtReturn;
        }
```